# How do I pass variables to a custom function in ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

Consider the following data:

```
d = data.frame(
    experiment = as.factor(c("foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar")),
    si = runif(5),
    ti = runif(5)
)
```

I would like to perform a correlation test for `si` and `ti`, for each `experiment` factor level. So I thought I'd run:

```
ddply(d, .(experiment), cor.test)
```

But how do I pass the values of `si` and `ti` to the `cor.test` call? I tried this:

```
> ddply(d, .(experiment), cor.test, x = si, y = ti)
Error in .fun(piece, ...) : object 'si' not found
> ddply(d, .(experiment), cor.test, si, ti)
Error in match.arg(alternative) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing? The `plyr` documentation does not include any example for me. Most commands I see only involve `summarize` as the function call, but doing the usual things I was used to doing from `summarize` don't work, as can be seen above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ddply splits your data frame by the variables you select (`experiment` here) and then passes the function the resulting subsets of the data frame.  In your case your function `cor.test` doesn't accept a data frame as an input, so you need a translation layer:

```
d <- data.frame(
  experiment = as.factor(c("foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar")),
  si = runif(6),
  ti = runif(6)
)
ddply(d, .(experiment), function(d.sub) cor.test(d.sub$si, d.sub$ti)$statistic)
#   experiment         t
# 1        bar 0.1517205
# 2        foo 0.3387682
```

Also, your output has to be something like a vector or a data frame, which is why I just chose `$statistic` above, but you could have added multiple variables if you wanted.

Side note, I had to add a value to the input data frame as it cor.test won't run on 2 values (was the case for "bar").  If you want more comprehensive stats, you can try:

```
ddply(d, .(experiment), function(d.sub) {
  as.data.frame(cor.test(d.sub$si, d.sub$ti)[c("statistic", "parameter", "p.value", "estimate")])
} )
#   experiment statistic parameter   p.value  estimate
# 1        bar 0.1517205         1 0.9041428 0.1500039
# 2        foo 0.3387682         1 0.7920584 0.3208567
```

Note that since we're now returning something more complex than just a vector, we need to coerce it to a data.frame.  If you want to include more complex values (e.g. the confidence interval, which is a two value result), you would have to simplify them first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarize` for this if you don't mind running `cor.test` several times for each experiment (i.e., performance isn't an issue).

```
#note that you need at least 3 value pairs for cor.test
set.seed(42)
d = data.frame(
  experiment = as.factor(c("foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar")),
  si = runif(6),
  ti = runif(6)
)

library(plyr)
ddply(d, .(experiment), summarize,
      r=cor.test(si, ti)$estimate,
      p=cor.test(si, ti)$p.value
      )

#  experiment           r         p
#1        bar  0.07401492 0.9528375
#2        foo -0.41842834 0.7251622
```